# How can we write $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ in handwriting?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $\bf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$  How can we write this $\bf{x}$ in note book. I mean in written handwriting  what is the notation for $\bf{x}$.

Comment: I genuinely have no clue what you are actually asking. It cannot be literally "how to write '$x\in\mathbb{R}^n$' with a pen," can it?

Comment: I guess he means the bold x.

Comment: I think it's about keeping consistent notation for vectors with hand-written math. It's easy to use bold font on a computer, less so on paper.

Comment: In handwriting, I would usually use $\vec{x}$.

Comment: Instead of bold font when hand-writing math, it's common to draw a little arrow over the vector.

Comment: I think the question is asking in particular about reproducing boldface by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, there are several ways to write bold face symbols like $\mathbf{x}$ on a blackboard (or on a sheet of paper): themes popular are

1. $\vec{x}$
2. $\underline{x}$.

Here in Italy I think that mathematicians would choose $\underline{x}$, while physicists and mathematical physicists would probably use $\vec{x}$. But contemporary mathematicians tend to simply write $x$.

Comment: Physicists and mathematical physicists almost always don't bother writing $\vec{x}$ for $x$ either. I have seen an abbreviation like $k[\underline{X}]$ for the polynomial ring $k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ in algebraic geometry, but I wouldn't say that that's a common usage.

Comment: @Siminore thanks

Answer (score 0):

An element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is written
$\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$

where each $x_i$ is a real number.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space